# Terraform source error - Error: Failed to query available provider packages

Tags: azure, azure-devops, devops, terraform-provider-azure

I am trying to deploy a new infrastructure using terraform (for the first time) and I am getting the following error. I've tried everything but nothing seems to fix the issue.

Looks like it is asking for a provider **hashicorp/azure** ?

Can anyone help please??

```
Initializing provider plugins...
- Finding latest version of hashicorp/azure...
- Finding hashicorp/azurerm versions matching "2.98.0"...
- Installing hashicorp/azurerm v2.98.0...
- Installed hashicorp/azurerm v2.98.0 (signed by HashiCorp)
╷
│ Error: Failed to query available provider packages
│ 
│ Could not retrieve the list of available versions for provider hashicorp/azure: provider registry registry.terraform.io does not have a provider named registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/azure
│ 
│ Did you intend to use terraform-providers/azure? If so, you must specify that source address in each module which requires that provider. To see which modules are currently depending on hashicorp/azure, run the following command:
│     terraform providers
╵

lucas@Azure:~$ terraform providers

Providers required by configuration:
.
├── provider[registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/azurerm] 2.98.0
└── provider[registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/azure]
```

The code that I am using to create the infrastructure is the below:

```
  required_providers {
    azurerm = {
      source  = "hashicorp/azurerm"
      version = "=2.98.0"
    }
  }
}

provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
  subscription_id = "910910be-a61e-4e1f-a72a-7e43456c0836"
}

# Create a resource group
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "rg" {
  name     = "default"
  location = "West Europe"
}

# Create a virtual network
resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "vpc" {
  name                = "default-network"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.rg.location
  address_space       = ["10.0.0.0/16"]
}

# Create frontend subnet
resource "azurerm_subnet" "subnet_frontend" {
  name                 = "internal"
  resource_group_name  = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  virtual_network_name = azurerm_virtual_network.vpc.name
  address_prefixes     = ["10.0.1.0/24"]
}

# Create backend subnet
resource "azurerm_subnet" "subnet_backend" {
  name                 = "internal"
  resource_group_name  = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  virtual_network_name = azurerm_virtual_network.vpc.name
  address_prefixes     = ["10.0.2.0/24"]
}

# Create frontend network interface
resource "azurerm_network_interface" "frontend_nic" {
  name                = "frontend_nic"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.rg.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name

  ip_configuration {
    name                          = "internal"
    subnet_id                     = azurerm_subnet.subnet_frontend.id
    private_ip_address_allocation = "Dynamic"
  }
}

# Create backend network interface
resource "azurerm_network_interface" "backend_nic" {
  name                = "backend_nic"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.rg.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name

  ip_configuration {
    name                          = "internal"
    subnet_id                     = azurerm_subnet.subnet_backend.id
    private_ip_address_allocation = "Dynamic"
  }
}

# Create frontend VM based on module
resource "azure_instance" "frontend" {
  source   = "./vm"
  name     = "frontend"
  rg       = module.azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  location = module.azurerm_resource_group.rg.location
  nic      = module.azurerm_network_interface.frontend_nic
}

# Create backend VM based on module
resource "azure_instance" "backend" {
  source   = "./vm"
  name     = "backend"
  rg       = module.azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  location = module.azurerm_resource_group.rg.location
  nic      = module.azurerm_network_interface.backend_nic
}
```

**My terraform version is: Terraform v1.1.5 and I am using on Azure CLI via bash.**

Any idea of what is causing this issue and how to fix it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This often happens when one accidentally specifies "hashicorp/azure" or "hashicorp/azurem" instead of "hashicorp/azurerm" in the required_providers block. Did you check the "vm" module referenced in the "azure_instance" module calls? There might be an erroneous "hashicorp/azure" specified there.

Comment: Hi lad. Yes, I've fixed this issue, thanks. Now I got another one. Please see below:

Comment: ```rror: Reference to undeclared module
│ 
│   on main.tf line 76, in resource "azurerm_virtual_machine" "frontend":
│   76:   location = module.azurerm_resource_group.rg.location
│ 
│ No module call named "azurerm_resource_group" is declared in the root module.
╵
╷
│ Error: Reference to undeclared module
│ 
│   on main.tf line 85, in resource "azurerm_virtual_machine" "backend":
│   85:   location = module.azurerm_resource_group.rg.location
│ 
│ No module call named "azurerm_resource_group" is declared in the root module. ```

Comment: @cdub regarding the second error, from line 74 -> 85, replace `module.azurerm_resource_group.rg.name` with `azurerm_resource_group.rg.name` & repeat for other lines as you aren't using any modules..

Answer (score 3):

My problem was more subtle.
All the provider were defined correctly but I had a data resource misspelled!

```
data "azure_virtual_network" "vnet" {
  name                = "my_vnet"
  resource_group_name = "my_rg"
}
```

As you can see I referred there to the data azure_ that is wrong. it should be:

```
data "azurerm_virtual_network" "vnet" {
  name                = "my_vnet"
  resource_group_name = "my_rg"
}
```

My suggestion is to search your code with the failing provider name. In this case `azure_` to find the problem.